# How can we disable specific dates in a DatePicker in the .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, datepicker

I am using the .NET Compact Framework in VS 2005.
How can we disable specific dates in a DatePicker in C#? And how can we disable all Saturdays?

Thanks

Comment: i take that back. its not a duplicate

Comment: @roadrunner whether any solution has given in the link for compactframework. i cannot change the datetime picker control.

Comment: Question is for compact framework.Does windows and compact framework same

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built-in method to do this.

You have a few options, such as:

- Using the built-in date picker, and then display a prompt if the user selects a Saturday,
- Build your own date picker control from scratch, though this would require a bit more work, or
- Use HTML to power your interface - there are many great date picker controls available for HTML, such as the one found in jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality for your requirement. What you would have to do is handling that in the date changed event.